# Correct way of using gen_tcp:connect with IPv6 Address

Tags: erlang, gen-tcp

Does anyone know how to connect to ipv6 tcp server address. Following tried but does not work.

```
{ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:connect("2a01:488:67:1000:253d:cd31:0:1", 5000, [{active, false},inet6]).
{error,enetunreach}
```

And this

```
{ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:connect("[2a01:488:67:1000:253d:cd31:0:1]", 5000, [{active, false},inet6]).
{error,nxdomain}
```

The server is reachable over IPv4 though.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the server reachable over IPv6 outside Erlang? When you say "reachable over IPv4", do you mean in Erlang? Do you mean by using (e.g.) "192.168.1.1" in the `gen_tcp:connect` call, or something else?

Comment: Yes by erlang in ipv4.

Comment: Fixed. Please ignore this it was port blocking for ipv6 addresses. thanks

Answer (score 1):

On shell A:

```
$erl

{ok, LSocket} = gen_tcp:listen(12345, [binary, {packet, line}, {active, true}, {reuseaddr, true}, inet6, {ip, {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}}]).
```

to test, on shell B:

```
$telnet ::1 12345
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual page of `gen_tcp` module, First argument of `connect/3-4` should be type of `inet:socket_address()` or `inet:hostname()`.
Try using [**This**](http://erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html#type-ip6_address) form of type.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}.We can also use your own IPv6 address.
Use **inet:parse_address("your IP address").**